# React Native print

Tags: react-native, printing

I would like to print text with my printer but I got the error: `ERROR  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'print' of null]`
However I correctly install the packages with `npm i react-native-print

I'm testing my react native App on Expo so I also tried the library `expo-print` but I don't found my printer inside my application. So I'm trying to use `react-native-print`

Package.json:

```
"react-native-print": "^0.11.0",
```

Here's my code:

```
import RNPrint from "react-native-print";
const printDocument = async () => {
    try {
      const options = {
        printerURL: "printer_ip",
        html: "<h1>Hello World</h1>",
      };
      await RNPrint.print(options);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

printDocument();
```